powershell script missing argument in parameter list
I am trying to run a powershell script that executes a python exe file which takes a json file as an argument.
I checked my json file, and the contents are valid.
My powershell script looks like so:
& "C:\RPA\0001-DHR\DHR_ConsolidateMarks\DHR_ConsolidateMarks.exe" test.json

The error message is:
At C:\Users\srv_hq-rpa-bot1\AppData\Local\Temp\Robin\f0f3xbjmnlo.tmp.ps1:1 char:75 + ... DHR\DHR_ConsolidateMarks\DHR_ConsolidateMarks.exe" {"Items":[{"Name": ... + ~~ Unexpected token ':[' in expression or statement. At C:\Users\srv_hq-rpa-bot1\AppData\Local\Temp\Robin\f0f3xbjmnlo.tmp.ps1:1 char:84 + ... dateMarks\DHR_ConsolidateMarks.exe" {"Items":[{"Name":"JAron","File": ... + ~~~~~~~~ Unexpected token ':"JAron"' in expression or statement. At C:\Users\srv_hq-rpa-bot1\AppData\Local\Temp\Robin\f0f3xbjmnlo.tmp.ps1:1 char:92 + ... ateMarks\DHR_ConsolidateMarks.exe" {"Items":[{"Name":"JAron","File":" ... + ~ Missing argument in parameter list. + CategoryInfo : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken 

Not sure what exactly is going wrong here since my JSON is valid and I do not see anything wrong with my powershell script. Any suggestions would help
Note: the .exe file was generated using pyinstaller --onedir so the python interpreter is packaged with the .exe

How are you invoking the powershell script? I can reproduce the error message if I run this in a Windows PowerShell interactive console session: & "C:\RPA\0001-DHR\DHR_ConsolidateMarks\DHR_ConsolidateMarks.exe" {"Items":[{"Name":"JAron","File":}]} - it looks like for whatever reason the test.json argument in your command is being replaced with the contents of the test.json file.

What happens if you run the Python script without using pyinstaller?

@lit it works fine without the pyinstaller becuase I run it on my local machine. The reason I need pyinstaller is because I need to distribute the exe to an unattended machine that does not have python installed.

@mclayton I invoke the powershell script with power automate desktop.
